# Conditional hook based on the core function that is calling it

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, core

In a Multisite, I'm applying the filter `get_blogs_of_user` to sort the "My Sites" admin bar menu, where the sites are listed by **`blogname`**:

[image: admin bar multisite my-sites]

What happens is that I'd like another order elsewhere, where the sites are listed by **`domain`**.
For example, the sites that appear in the Users screen (`/wp-admin/network/users.php`):

[image: user sites]

The question is: for achieving that, I'm using [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), but am not sure if this is working by accident or if the logic stands (?!).

I found that checking for `debug_trace()->trace[4]['function']` I get to know where in the core the function `get_blogs_of_user` is being called.

### Sample code

```
add_filter( 'get_blogs_of_user', 'bf_reorder_users_sites' );

function bf_reorder_users_sites( $blogs ) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    // my_debug_dump();

    if( 'initialize' == $trace[4]['function'] )
        uasort( $blogs, 'bf_uasort_by_blogname' );
    else
        uasort( $blogs, 'bf_uasort_by_domain' );

    return $blogs;
}

function bf_uasort_by_domain( $a, $b ) {
    return strcasecmp( $a->domain, $b->domain );
}

function bf_uasort_by_blogname( $a, $b ) {
    return strcasecmp( $a->blogname, $b->blogname );
}
```

### Debug

`my_debug_dump()` lists `$trace[4]['file']` and `$trace[4]['function']`, and prints:

```
File:: /wp-path/wp-includes/admin-bar.php
Function:: initialize
--------
File:: /wp-path/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php
Function:: get_active_blog_for_user
--------
File:: /wp-path/wp-admin/admin-header.php
Function:: wp_user_settings
--------
File:: /wp-path/wp-includes/admin-bar.php
Function:: is_user_member_of_blog
--------
File:: /wp-path/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php
Function:: display_rows
--------
File:: /wp-path/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php
Function:: display_rows
--------
File:: /wp-path/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php
Function:: display_rows
```

Comment: Maybe there's a better title to describe this. If so, please modify it. (oh, yes, I'm using toscho's [Clean Admin](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Clean-Admin) for having that interface:)

Comment: Have you tried to switch the logic after the hook `wp_after_admin_bar_render`?

Comment: @toscho, yes! Much more elegant, will post an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much probably, using `debug_backtrace` in this fashion is wild hackerism...

Based on @toscho's tip, the following achieves the same results:

```
add_filter( 'get_blogs_of_user', 'reorder_users_sites' );

function reorder_users_sites( $blogs ) 
{
    if( !did_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render' ) )
        uasort( $blogs, 'bf_uasort_by_blogname' );
    else 
        uasort( $blogs, 'bf_uasort_by_domain' );

    return $blogs;
}
```